# Get a count of an enum if its value has been changed in the past month based on an updated_at column

Tags: sql, postgresql

Apologies in advance if the title was unclear. I'll try to explain more here.

I have two tables, a non-temporal table and a temporal version of that table that stores the updated_at value of a row, and its historical values.

I want to count all the values of a row (in the non-temporal table) that have changed in the past 30 days, using the temporal table.
These values are enums.

Here's an example.

```sql
create temporary table headcount (id int, hiring_status text, pay float);

create temporary table headcount_history (id int, hiring_status text, pay float, updated_at date);

insert into headcount values 
    (1, 'interviewing', 1000.00),
    (2, 'hired', 1000.00),
    (3, 'scouting', 1000.00),
    (4, 'interviewing', 100.12),
    (5, 'scouting', 123.42);

insert into headcount_history values 
    (1, 'scouting', 1000.00, '2022-07-25'),
    (1, 'scouting', 1005.00, '2022-07-26'),
    (1, 'scouting', 1005.00, '2022-07-27'),
    (1, 'interviewing', 1005.00, '2022-07-28'),

    (2, 'scouting', 1000.00, '2022-03-20'),
    (2, 'interviewing', 1000.00,'2022-04-20'),
    (2, 'hired', 3230.00, '2022-4-23'),
    (2, 'hired', 1000.00, '2022-4-25'),


    (3, 'scouting', 1000.00, '2022-03-20'),
    (3, 'interviewing', 1000.00,'2022-04-20'),
    (3, 'scouting', 1000.00, '2022-7-25'),

    (4, 'scouting', 1000.00, '2022-6-25'),
    (4, 'interviewing', 100.12, '2022-7-25'),

    (5, 'scouting', 1000.0, '2022-6-29'),
    (5, 'scouting', 123.42, '2022-7-10');

/* 
The goal is to find the number of hiring_statuses that were changed in the past 30 days 
for each hiring_status.

this is expected output 

scouting | interviewing | hired 
2        | 2            | 0
```

here's a link to a  db fiddle - https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=79ebffe4a28ef67d8552d36d47e967e7

I'm using postgres 13

Comment: Hey, I hope I understand what you want: in headcount_history table order by updated_at desc for each id only one latest record then you want count the hiring_status?

Answer (score 1):

```
    select  sum(coalesce(hired,0)) hired,
            sum(coalesce(scouting,0)) scouting,
            sum(coalesce(interviewing,0)) interviewing
    from
    (
    select  case when hiring_status ='hired' then h_cnt end "hired",
            case when hiring_status ='scouting' then h_cnt end "scouting",
            case when hiring_status ='interviewing' then h_cnt end "interviewing"
    from
    (
    
        select b.hiring_status,coalesce(a.cnt,0) h_cnt
        from 
        (select     hiring_status,
                count(1) cnt
        from    headcount_history 
        where   updated_at between current_date and current_date - interval '-30 days' 
        group by hiring_status) A right outer join
        (select     hiring_status
        from    headcount_history
        group by hiring_status)B
        on a.hiring_status = b.hiring_status
    )AA
    ) BB
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).